# Accessing SQL Server 2008 using Windows authentication in ASP.NET website

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, web-config

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008.

SQL Server has Window authentication, can I use this Windows server authentication in connection string of `web.config` file for ASP.NET application ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, create a udl file: 
open new file in notepad, save it as connection.udl
double click the empty file and windows will open a connection editor applet. navigate to your database, make sure it tests ok. Open the udl file in notepad again, and that is your correctly formated connection string. Alternately add a linq class to your app and get automatically created classes against any stored procedures or tables you drag on to the design surface